# Draining spherical tank

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I'm solving a standard problem of draining a tank through a small hole at the bottom of a half-spherical tank with radius $=R$, with the hole having a radius $a$. I want to find the diff. eq. for the height of the fluid w.r.t. time i.e. $\frac{dh}{dt}$, after finding an expression for the velocity $v_0$ of the fluid through the small hole.

My issue is that the hint in the problem gives that as the hole is very small it means I can assume the fluid velocity in the tank to be zero; $v_1 = 0$. For finding the exit velocity $u$ this is fine as it as usual gives via Toricelli's law: $u = \sqrt{2gh}$.

For finding $\frac{dh}{dt}$ however I use the continuity equation $v_1A_1=v_0A_0$ where $A_0 = a^2\pi$, $A_1$ the area of the surface; $A_1 = \pi h(t)(2R-h(t))$ and $v_1 = -\frac{dh}{dt}$. Solving, I find $\frac{dh}{dt} = a^2 \sqrt{2g} \frac{\sqrt{h}}{2hR-h^2}$. Separating and integrating for the total time to drain as $h$: $h \rightarrow 0; $ $t$: $0 \rightarrow t$, I find: $t(h) = \frac{20hR^{3/2}-5R^{5/2}}{15a^2\sqrt{2g}}$. Which, for a full tank $h=R$, gives: $t(h=R) = \frac{R^{5/2}}{a^2\sqrt{2g}}$ which seems reasonable to me.

However, where I feel uncomfortable is that I've used two expressions for $v_1$, one as it being equal to zero $v_1=0$ as per the hint and one as the velocity of the surface $v_1=-\frac{dh}{dt}$.

Comment: May I recommend $a$ rather than $A$ for the hole radius?

Comment: I agree with your answer to the problem – up to a numerical factor.

Comment: This is NOT a homework-like question. Help is not being sought with finding a solution. An apparent contradiction is pointed out – and this is sort of 'contradiction' is not specific to this problem. Its resolution is of more general interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torricelli's law for a liquid whose top surface area, $A_1$, isn't necessarily *much* greater than the area, $A_0$, of the exit hole in the container is
$$\tfrac 12 v_1^{\ 2}+gh=\tfrac 12 v_0^{\ 2}.$$
I suggest that you start with this in your derivation and, at the appropriate stage, bring in $A_1\gg A_0$, leading, via the continuity equation, to $v_0\gg v_1$. You are then entitled to neglect $v_1^{\ 2}$ *in comparison with* $v_0^{\ 2}$ in Torricelli's equation, but recognising that you are making an approximation. The roles of $v_1$ and $v_0$ are quite different in the continuity equation, and putting $v_1=0$ in this equation would not be justified.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, using the continuity equation in Torricelli's law as you stated and then $A_1 \gg A_0$ leads me to the same expression for $v_0 = \sqrt{2gh}$ without having to, as the hint said take $v_1 = 0$ off the bat. But it effectively leads to the same effect in that the squared velocity $v_1^2 \ll v_0^2$, i.e. in Torricelli's law as you stated I can take $v_1^2 \approx 0$? The hint still confuses me then, as what good does it do really?

Comment: And so then I can still use the same derivation as I did for finding $\frac{dh}{dt}$ as $\frac{dh}{dt}=-v_1$?

Comment: "what good does it do really?" It shows why you can put $v_1=0$ in Torricelli's equation, in which $v_1^{\ 2}$ is to be subtracted from $v_0^{\ 2}$, so the equation is left almost unaltered by putting $v_1=0$, whereas you can't sensibly put $v_1=0$ in the continuity equation.

Comment: But had it not been more clear saying that the squared differences $v_0^2-v_1^2$ can be approximated as $v_0^2-v_1^2 \approx v_0^2$ or something along those lines?

Comment: I think that your way of putting it is pretty much equivalent to mine. Maybe you'll get another answer that is more to your taste.